# Realtime processing and callbacks with Python and C++

Tags: c++, python, callback, real-time

I need to write code to do some realtime processing that is fairly computationally complex. I would like to create some Python classes to manage all my scripting, and leave the intensive parts of the algorithm coded in C++ so that they can run as fast as possible.  I would like to instantiate the objects in Python, and have the C++ algorithms chime back into the script with callbacks in python.  Something like:

```
myObject = MyObject()
myObject.setCallback(myCallback)
myObject.run()

def myCallback(val):
    """Do something with the value passed back to the python script."""
    pass
```

Will this be possible?  How can I run a callback in python from a loop that is running in a C++ module?  Anyone have a link or a tutorial to help me do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using Boost.Python as suggested by ChristopheD.  A gotcha would be if the C++ extension is running in it's own thread context (not created by Python).  If that's the case, make sure to use the [`PyGILState_Ensure()` and `PyGILState_Release()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#PyGILState_Ensure) functions when calling into Python code from C++.

From the docs (http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock):

> Beginning with version 2.3, threads
>   can now take advantage of the
>   PyGILState_*()  functions to do all of
>   the above automatically. The typical
>   idiom for calling into Python from a C
>   thread is now:
>
> ```
> PyGILState_STATE gstate;
> gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
>
> /* Perform Python actions here.  */
> result = CallSomeFunction();
> /* evaluate result */
>
> /* Release the thread. No Python API allowed beyond this point. */
> PyGILState_Release(gstate)
> ```

I recommend making the callbacks short & sweet - to limit the need to perform exception handling in C++ code.  If you're using wxPython, you could use it's robust async event system.  Or the callbacks could put events on a Queue and you could have a thread devoted to asynchronously executing callback/event code.

Even with Boost.Python magic, you'll have to get familiar with this portion of the Python C API when dealing with threads.  (Don't forget to wrap the C++ functions with `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` to release the GIL!)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html). Its tutorial starts [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://hg.cython.org/cython/file/8bff3332e34f/Demos/callback) is an example of how to do python callbacks using [Cython](http://www.cython.org/).  It might be worth looking at [Pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/) as well.  Both can make integrating C/C++ with Python rather easy.

Answer (score 0):

We do what you are doing a lot at work.  We like python but it's just not fast enough sometimes.
[Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) and [Swig](https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html) are both good for doing that. You should also check out this link on Python [Performance](https://web.archive.org/web/20120529060705/http://www.scipy.org:80/PerformancePython) they talk a little about [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) which may help you.